# link-monitoring in fortigate

Tags: router, firewall, isp, fortigate, failover

[image][image: bgp[![][1]]][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MvDaG.png)i am trying for a failover between two ISP interfaces using link-monitor in fortigate. both ISP links are vlan interface ( ie, not physical). and with my primary ISP, i have eBGP. i need to monitor the link performance, when packet loss through link, make bgp down, so that traffic will be shifted to ISP 2 ( i have static default route through ISP 2 with higher metric).
But in fortigate i have only make interface down ( which is not a good idea obviously) or remove static route through that interface ( which won't work for me, my last mile protocol is eBGP).
If any body is able to give any work around, it will be great.

device configuration
config system link-monitor
    edit "to_105"
        set srcintf "wan"
        set server "xx.xx.xx.xx"
        set protocol http
        set gateway-ip yy.yy.yy.yy
        set update-cascade-interface enable
        set update-static-route enable

[image: my rough network diagram is included.]

Comment: You need to edit your question to give us more information. A good description (or even better, a diagram) of how the network is connected, the network device models, and the network device configurations.

Comment: question is updated

Comment: You need to give us the (sanitized) configuration. Obfuscate the public addresses and passwords, but give us the whole configuration.

Comment: Please, never use an image for text. Just paste in the text and use the Preformatted Text feature (`{}`) on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got confirmation from fortinet that, link-monitor wont be able to control dynamic routing protocol.